# there's no sound in the headphones when I open the video

Tags: ios, webrtc, avaudiosession

I pod 'webRTC' into my App. I plug in the headphones before I open the video, and there's no sound in the headphones, and the sound comes out of the speaker. However,I plug in the headphones after opening the video,sound comes out of headphones. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.This is my code:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
```

And, It does not work when I try to code like this:

```
 BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord mode:AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat options:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are using overrideSpeaker as default.
you just have to play with overrideOutputAudioPort.
there are some key points while using loudspeaker and secondary speakers that I face.

1. when you want to route audio from Loudspeaker user

   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
   overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker
   error:nil];

   and if you want to use the secondary speaker or external peripheral use.

   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
   overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone
   error:nil];
2. while signalling process is working (creating/accepting offer and answer) 
   default speaker route should be on AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone. or it will change autometically to AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone.
3. you can change audio route by using overrideOutputAudioPort method inside the application.

   Hope it will help you.

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely, i think that i made a mistake.  it works when i change my code  like this:  `- (void)enableSpeaker {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord mode:AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat options:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];    
    _isSpeakerEnabled = YES;
}`

Comment: (y)  can you please upvote if you think My answer helped you.